# Calling a web service from a .net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I need to call a web service from a .net web application, here is my code:

```
LoginRequest req = new LoginRequest();
LoginRequestBody reqBody = new LoginRequestBody();

reqBody.username = txtUsername.Text;
reqBody.password = txtPassword.Text;

req.Body = reqBody;

LoginResponse resp = new LoginResponse();
LoginResponseBody respBody = new LoginResponseBody();

resp.Body = respBody;
MessageBox.Show(respBody.LoginResult.ToString());
```

The message returned is always false, while the message from the web service (when I test directly) is returning true, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Do the constructors of `LoginResponse` or `LoginResponseBody` do anything? If would guess they don't, in which case your problem is that you never call the web service

Answer (score 6):

You are not actually calling the web-service! You should not be creating a response directly - you should be asking the web-service for one, e.g.

```
LoginResponse response = LoginService.Login(req);
```

However, I don't know what your service is actually called, so the above is just a sample.

Comment: my web service is called OAAuthentication, but inside it there is only loginrequest, loginrequestBody, loginresponse, loginresponseBody, Service1Soap, Service1SoapChannel and Service1SoapClient

Comment: my method in the web service is called Login